# GtkEventBox connect signal to GAction in Glade

Tags: rust, gtk, glade

I am trying to connect the `enter-notify-event` of an GtkEventBox to an attached GAction via Glade. Checking the running application with GtkInspector shows nothing connected to the `enter-notify-event` signal.

I'm following [this blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/jsparber/2018/12/26/i-fell-in-love-with-gaction/) which states:

> You could also set the properties via the .ui file. When you replace the event handlers of clicks with actions you can really streamline your code base.

So I think this should somehow be possible. It only mentions a click handler of a GtkButton, but I don't see why it should be different with other signals.

Glade:

[image: glade]

Inspector:

[image: inspector]

```
<object class="GtkEventBox" id="service_row">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="enter-notify-event" handler="test.show-arrow" swapped="no"/>
```

([complete UI file](https://pastebin.com/3njP04LL))

```
let actions = SimpleActionGroup::new();
let show_arrow = SimpleAction::new("show-arrow", None);
actions.add_action(&show_arrow);
show_arrow.connect_activate(move |_action, _data| {
   println!("enter row2");
});
row.insert_action_group("test", &actions);
// row.connect_enter_notify_event(move |_widget, _crossing| {
//     actions.activate_action("show-arrow", None);
//     Inhibit(false)
// });
```

Manually activating the GAction via code like in the commended out lines works just fine. And the action also shows up in the Inspector when looking at the EventBox.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. [`GtkActionable`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkActionable.html#GtkActionable.implementations) is only implemented for widgets that have a clear user-activate action, such as buttons or menu items. In particular `GtkEventBox` does not implement it.

And even if it did, this interface will only manage one event per class, the *activate* action, not the `enter-notify-event` you are interested in.

So, I'm afraid that you'll have to keep manually connecting your event.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but thank you for explaining everything in such detail :)